# .htaccess not being read properly from DocumentRoot dir

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, centos

I have a codeigniter project installed in /var/www/html.
URLs should look like this: http://example.com/clients/abc
I am running CentOS and Apache 2.2.15

In order to get the routes to work properly I have enabled mod_rewrite (which I can see is on through phpinfo.php) and AllowOverride All in httpd.conf.

My documentroot defined in httpd.conf is /var/www/html.

The .htaccess file in /var/www/html is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Just this by itself I get 404 pages on all my controllers and none of my contollers/views render other than index.

However. If I create a second .htaccess file in /var/www and put this one line in it:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Now my rewrite works and my controllers and all my pages load properly. However I still get a 404 page not found in firebug yet my pages still load.

There is some kind of weird and crazy thing happening here that I do not understand or respect. Double redirects? Apache doesn't know what DocumentRoot means? Why is the /var/www/html/.htaccess file not being recognized unless I have another .htaccess file in /var/www?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem.

In httpd.conf I changed

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride none
```

to

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
```

This was difficult to spot because there were a significant amount of comments within that Directory setting and it obscured it. There were numerous other AllowOverride All statements in the .conf file too which made me think I had the setting set already.

## BUT WAIT, there's more!

Also I learned from a guy named 'thumbs' on IRC that I should just place the contents of my .htaccess file right into the <Directory> settings in httpd.conf. When you do that you can change back to AllowOverride none and get a significant performance boost.